# WordPress css not loading after adding Adsense code into header.php

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, adsense

After adding the code of google AdSense given by Google into the header.php file of my currently running WordPress theme, the css of website gets fail and sites load with scattered images and text. But when I remove AdSense code, css works properly. What should do to fix it?

Following is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `<head></head>` before the existing `<head>`. and then add your adsense code into it. It will definitely work fine.